# Gvim Syntax Customization

Tags: syntax, vim

How can I make Gvim to treat(syntax highlighting) lines starting with # and ; in an assembly file as comment ? Meaning in addition to ; (which is normally the way to represent comment in assembly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is being recognised as Assembler, it will have it; `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/asm.vim` has the line `syn match asmComment      "[#;!|].*" contains=asmTodo` which matches `#` lines as comments.

Going by the contents of Vim 7.3's `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`, `.asm`, `.s`, `.S`, `.a`, `.A`, `.mac` and `.lst` files will all be recognised as Assembler. If you are having a different extension, look at `:set ft` to see what it's being recognised. You may need to override it in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.whatever setf asm
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

On you installation, you have a file called `syntax\asm.vim` which should define color syntax rules for assembly.

On my installation, I got the following line:
`syn match asmComment       "[#;!|].*" contains=asmTodo`

Which means that lines starting by # (or ;) should be considered as comments and it does work on my installation.

You can check in filetype.vim if the file you are working on is recognized as asm.

In your .vimrc or .gvimrc which are vim configuration files, you need :
`" Syntax highlighting and filetypes

filetype plugin indent on

syntax on`